# Cyberpanel You are not authorized to access this resource

Tags: github, cyber-panel

I am new to Cyberpanel and would like to integrate it with my existing github repo but I get `You are not authorized to access this resource.` when I try manage git on cyberpanel user interface. I tried following following docs and added the new ssh key to github but again it's not connected.

- https://cyberpanel.net/docs/how-to-use-git-manager-in-cyberpanel/
- https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-use-cyberpanel-git-manager-for-complete-automation/30630

Tech stack:

- AWS Cyberpanel 2.1 with Ubuntu OS
- Github public repo for test

Comment: hi @saeedj Did you find answer to this? 
I too have setup by my own Cyberpanel Server and was trying to use the 'Manage GIT' feature of project.

But I cannot connect it with Bitbucket

Comment: Is any news here? This started to happen to me also

Comment: After lots of googling, it seems many people (including me) are having the same problem. We have all added our deploy keys but still no authorization is recognised. In many cases CyberPanel just stop replying or trying to help other than posting the same link (https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-use-cyberpanel-git-manager-for-complete-automation/30630) that simply doesn't work. I assume this is an issue in the CyberPanel software rather than all of it's users.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the following format:

[image]